# Tic-Tac-Toe(problem to my check winner) Python

Tags: python

i have this weird bug i must say or might not.. im just a beginner btw. I can obviously look up to the internet for the solution but i dont want to because to be honest this should work right but the problem on this is on the output after 4 moves my checkwin functions got declared when none of my if statement hit True:

```
def checkwin(boards):
if boards[0] and boards[3] and boards[6] == 'x':  
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[0] and boards[4] and boards[8] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[0] and boards[1] and boards[2] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[2] and boards[5] and boards[8] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[6] and boards[7] and boards[8] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[3] and boards[4] and boards[5] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[1] and boards[4] and boards[7] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
elif boards[6] and boards[4] and boards[2] == 'x':
    print('Theres a winner')
else:
    print('still no winner')
```

main code:

```
def player1(boards):
on = True
print("player 1 you are {}".format(ran1))
while on:
    try:
        playerone = (input("where to put:"))
        num = int(playerone) - 1

        if num >= 9:
            print('you exceeded only 1-9')
            continue
        elif boards[num] == '-':
            boards[num] = ran1

        elif boards[num] != '-':
            print('Its already played!')
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('please print numbers only')
        continue
    on = False
displayboard(boards)


def player2(boards):
    on = True
    print('playertwo you are {}'.format(ran2))
    while on:
        try:
            playertwo = input('player two where to put:')
            num = int(playertwo) - 1
            if num >= 9:
                print('you are {} and be sure number is 1-9 only'.format(ran2))
                continue
            elif boards[num] == '-':
                boards[num] = ran2
            elif boards[num] != '-':
                print('Its already played!')
                continue
            else:
                print('Its already played!')
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print('please print numbers only')
            continue

        on = False
    displayboard(boards)



def displayboard(boards):
print(boards[0] + "|" + boards[1] + "|" +boards[2])
print(boards[3] + "|" + boards[4] + "|" +boards[5])
print(boards[6] + "|" + boards[7] + "|" + boards[8])


def main():
on = True

while on:
    player1(board)
    player2(board)

    checkwin(board)
```

then after i play like 4 moves or even 3 moves it declares theres a winner which is weird because ive never establish it on checkwinner function

output:

```
x|o|x    #[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
o|-|-
-|-|-
theres a winner
```

to be honest i can just look up on the internet and copy paste from them because it is much neater but my mind just cant move on from these cause i dont know what happens wrong

Comment: @TomKarzes or `if a == b == c` in short

Comment: Small tip: You should have an array of win combos, and then iterate over them.
What I would recommend is that you check every combo, make sure all the cells are the same and not empty, and then declare the winner as the value of any cell that made the combo.

Comment: @DeepSpace I get it now.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Oops, good point.  I'm just going to delete it.